# What wishes are said during the Korean New Year holiday/설날?

Tags: vocabulary

What greetings or wishes are typically or traditionally said on during the Korean New Year holiday, 설날 (Jan. 28, 2017)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 새해 복 많이 받으세요!

Literally, it means: "May you receive many fortunes in the New Year!" (Often you will see "행복" 복 written as 福, which is the Chinese character for fortune, happiness, or good luck. In addition, 복/福 is often written on a small money pouch: monetary fortune.)

- Google Translation: "Best wishes for a Happy New Year!"
- Papago translation: "Happy New Year!"

[Google image search for 새해 복 많이 받으세요](https://www.google.com/search?q=%EC%83%88%ED%95%B4%20%EB%B3%B5%20%EB%A7%8E%EC%9D%B4%20%EB%B0%9B%EC%9C%BC%EC%84%B8%EC%9A%94&tbm=isch) shows many representative examples. I picked out a good one below:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat formal phrase that you might see in written language is

> 꿈과 소망을 이루시길 빌어요!

Something like "may your dreams and wishes come true".

Source: My (native) Korean teacher